# [[]]*X does not create unique arrays

Tags: python

When running

```py
a = [[]]*5
a[1].append("test")
print(a) # [["test"], ["test"], ["test"], ["test"], ["test"]]
```

how can you achieve [[], ["test"], [], [], []] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension.

```
a = [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

Otherwise, you are just duplicating the same reference to a single empty list.

List multiplication does what you want so rarely that's it's hardly worth using it when it *is* appropriate. For example, `[0]*5` won't cause problems, because `0` is an immutable value. When `[0 for _ in range(5)]` creates a semantically equivalent list, and you almost never *want* what `[[]]*5` produces, it's easier for everyone involved to simply always avoid explicit shared references.

(CPython, as an optimization, keeps a cache of `int` values between -5 and 257--give or take a few at either end of the interval--, so `[0 for _ in range(5)]` and `[0]*5` end up producing the same list of shared references anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```
a = [[] for _ in range(5)]
a[1].append("test")
print(a) # [[], ['test'], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the direct assignment like

```
a = [[]]*5
a[1] = ["test"]
print(a) # [[], ["test"], [], [], []]
```